# To create a dynamic form in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a form in Excel in which few questions are asked and then when submit button is typed all the data gets stored at the back hand and an empty form again comes up.

I started writing the code but cannot understand how to select the empty cell every time the form is filled and the submit button is clicked.

Attached below is the code I tried

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select = "=Sheet1!RC[1]"

End Sub
```

It is giving me error can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you are trying to perform an operation when using a .Select statement.  As a general rule, you should always try to avoid .Select statements. They are unnecessary and slow down code execution.  Give something like this a try instead:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!RC[1]"
```